# How can EC2 internal (10.X.X.X) IP addresses be mapped externally?

Tags: nat, ip-address, internal-dns, host

On our work internal network we've got a link to an Amazon domain.

One of the servers we're talking to is: 10.29.112.X. Now this address starts with 10, so I expect it is an internally mapped address that has no external meaning.

When I search for this on http://ip-address-lookup-v4.com/ I see that it is an EC2 server. (Host name: ip-10-29-112-X.ec2.internal).

To me this doesn't seem possible.

My question is: **How can EC2 internal (10.X.X.X)  IP addresses be mapped externally?**

Comment: My home's internal network is 10.0.1.0/24. A lookup of my router using the site you provided returns "Host name:ip-10-0-1-1.ec2.internal" -- does that mean my home network is hosted on AWS? Or is it possible that site is just guessing? Try running `whois 10.29.112.x` and compare to that site's results.

Comment: what happens if you run `curl ifconfig.me/all` ? I suspect the machine has an EIP and the reverse DNS has been set to its private address rather than its EIP